# Within how many days to enter Bahrain after getting visa

Tags: working-visas, bahrain

I have been offered a job in Bahrain by a company.They would be applying for a visa for me shortly and have asked to me resign only once I receive the visa.

As I have a notice period of 90 days with my current employer, i can only leave my current job and leave India only after 91 - 95 days once I get the visa.

So the question is is there a time period as per the immigration laws, within which I would need to enter Bahrain and join my sponsor company after receiving the visa?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a visitor visa which you must use within 30 days of issuance, the work visa is submitted to, and issued by the [Labour Market Regulatory Authority](http://lmra.bh/portal/en/home). Your employer, in its sponsorship letter, had to include the duration of the contact being offered to you; the work visa coincides with that time period.

> LMRA’s total processing time is between 1 and 10 business days, provided that all the submitted information and documents were correct and clear and that the requirements were fulfilled at the time of submission.

With a 3-month notice required by your current employer, you may have to review your options, whether to resign immediately in anticipation of the new job, ask your new employer whether it’s willing to wait three months for you to begin, or accept any repercussions of leaving your current employer on short notice.

Comment: So Ill be joining my new employer in Bahrain next month beginning. My visa says Permit period is 24 months. But expires on 29 Nov this year. What does that mean

Comment: @MordernRPGSoldier that should be asked of the authorities but, at a guess, it means you have to until 29 Nov to enter the country, basically 90 days from issuance. As you note, you there have a work permit valid for 2 years.

Comment: It's more than 90 days my visa was issued in may 30 so it's a six month validity